# Calculate $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n \\ r\end{smallmatrix}\right)/{k^n}$ for very large $n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How to calculate large $ \frac{\left(\begin{matrix}n \\ r\end{matrix}\right)}{k^n}$, given very large $n$.
Since n is large enough normal methods of calculating $ \left(\begin{matrix}n \\ r\end{matrix}\right)$ won't work under requied complexity.
Also since n is large , simulataneous division with number is required to prevent overflow .
Suggest a method to do so.

Comment: is it ? $$ \frac{\left(\begin{matrix}n \\ r\end{matrix}\right)}{k^n}$$

Comment: Is "$\text{number}$" special?

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Yes

Comment: Do you need an exact result or an approximate value ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No it can be categorized into powers of prime(if needed)

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea is just to represent number in form p1^a1*p2^a2*p3^a3...*pt^at,
for every number we use the same style of format. Then for multiplication it is simply the add of the exponent number and division is simply for subtraction, and power is just multiply the same n for every exponent numbers of ai.

Since we can decompose n into its basic form in around log(n) times(since, there are around log(n) primes numbers under n. We could use eratosthenes sieve method to pre calculate the primes list. This can work n up to 10^14 under 1 seconds in a modern computer.

Comment: @moonlight True that . But numerator is not n ,it is nCr so how can we decompose the numerator into primes .

Comment: @user252697 If r is small or (n - r) is small, I will just iterate over r to do the multiplication and division. If r is as large as n, there is a method to calculate nCr (mod p) in log(n) time complexity using [Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) .  But if you want exact number of the problem, I don't know whether there is a efficient algorithm to do it.

Comment: Ya.I know that . But it is for modular function but here i have to divide nCr with number.

Comment: @user252697: So I think you can only get exact answer for small r or small (n - r) values. Is there any constrain of r?